# How can I find all uses of a ValueDecl?

Tags: clang, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, static-analysis

I'd like to take clang AST, analyze how a certain variable is used and do some
source-to-source transformation if a specific usage pattern is recognized.
Particularly, I'm looking for patterns like this:

```
void *h;
h = create_handler(...);
use_handler(h);
destroy_handler(h);
```

So far, I am able to detect `ValueDecl` corresponding to `void *h`. Next step
would be to find all uses of `h` and see if they are safe and if
`create_handler/destroy_handler` properly dominate/post-dominate one another.
Unfortunately, I have no idea how to iterate over `h`'s uses, it seems that
there is no such interface in `ValueDecl` class.

I'd appreciate it if you could you either suggest how I could find all uses of a
variable in AST, or point me to some clang-based tool dealing with a similar problem.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can match `declRefExpr`s referencing the variable (using AST matchers). After that, `ParentMap` could be used to traverse AST backward and find recursively AST nodes which use those `declRefExpr`s. Keep in mind that typically `ParentMap` is constructed not for the whole AST but for a subtree only (passed as a parameter into the constructor).